# Application.match with multiple control inputs - Does it work?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I've spent probably 2 days trying to fix this code to make it work. Its actually a very simple credit entry to a statement of accounts database that I'm trying to compile.

The userform looks something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4F3J.jpg

Where the top textboxes are named ClientTextBox and DebitTextBox respectively
and the bottom 10 + 10 textboxes are named Inv1, Inv2... Inv20. The invoice textboxes are to reference which invoices that the cheques we have received will be paying. E.g. We received a cheque with "$100" from Client "ABC" to pay for invoice "001" and "002". Hence 001 and 002 are entered into the invoice textboxes 1 and 2 with the remaining left blank.

Msgboxes were added along the way for error checking. I used the "Like" function to differentiate the top textboxes with the invoice textboxes to differentiate the input, as seen here:

```
For Each Ctr In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(Ctr) = "TextBox" And Ctr.Name Like "Inv#*" Then
```

This worked fine. But the area of particular concern  was in this section of code:

```
If Ctr.value <> "" Then
            MsgBox ("Found a value!" & vbNewLine & Ctr.value)
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Worksheets("SOA").Range("A:A"), Ctr.value) Then
                    V = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ctr.value, .Worksheets("SOA").Range("A:A"), 0)
                        If .Worksheets("SOA").Range(V, 7).value = "Unpaid" Then
                            .Worksheets("SOA").Range(V, 7).value = "Paid"
```

The Application.worksheetfunction.match is virtually unable to match any variable (e.g. Y = Ctr.value) with an error 1004 but works when I change Ctr.value to 1, like this:

```
 V = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, .Worksheets("SOA").Range("A:A"), 0)
```

I am new to userforms so I don't quite get some of its limitations. Any suggestions would be most welcome! I just learnt VBA coding about a week ago so I'm sure that I've got a long way to go. Here is the full code:

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()

Dim SOA As ListObject
Dim Ctr As Control
Dim pPage As msforms.Page
Dim credit As ListRow
Dim V As Variant
With ThisWorkbook

Set SOA = .Worksheets("SOA").ListObjects(1) 'table name

Set credit = SOA.ListRows.Add(1) 'the new row, always add to the top
credit.Range(1, 2).value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd") 'Date

credit.Range(1, 3).value = ClientTextBox.value 'Client name
credit.Range(1, 6).value = DebitTextBox.value 'Credit Amt

For Each Ctr In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(Ctr) = "TextBox" And Ctr.Name Like "Inv#*" Then
        MsgBox (Ctr.Name)
        If Ctr.value <> "" Then
            MsgBox ("Found a value!" & vbNewLine & Ctr.value)
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Worksheets("SOA").Range("A:A"), Ctr.value) Then
                    V = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ctr.value, .Worksheets("SOA").Range("A:A"), 0)
                        If .Worksheets("SOA").Range(V, 7).value = "Unpaid" Then
                            .Worksheets("SOA").Range(V, 7).value = "Paid"
                        Else: MsgBox ("Invoice #" & Ctr.value & " has already been paid!")
                        End If
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Didn't find the number")
                End If
        End If
    End If
Next

End With

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Ctr.Value` is a String value. E.g. "1".

The `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Worksheets("SOA").Range("A:A"), Ctr.value)` will count even if the values in the Range are numbers. This is because the second parameter of CountIf is expected as a String since it could also be ">1" or "<1" or "<>1".

But `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ctr.value, .Worksheets("SOA").Range("A:A"), 0)` will not match if the `Ctr.Value` is "1" but the values in the range are numbers.

So if the values in the range are numbers, you must convert `Ctr.Value` to a number  value before using in `Match`.

Example:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Ctr.value), .Worksheets("SOA").Range("A:A"), 0)
```

Comment: Dude you are a hero! I know how silly I must look now but I didn't know that ctr.value got inputed as a string!